# Exchange the setup account

Tags: 2013, service-account, setup

I need to exchange the setup account I have used to install and configure an entire SharePoint farm. Apparently I had received a 'non-permanent' account which now needs to be replaced with a proper kind.

How can this be done? I really want to make sure that I don't lose any permissions with my new setup account.

I'm running SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your setup account used for the following task:

- Setup
- SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard
- Configure and manage the server farm.
- Act as the application pool identity for the SharePoint Central
  Administration Web site.
- Run the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service.

Then make sure the following permission exists.

- Local Administrator on all the SharePoint Servers
- SecurityAdmin and DB_Creator rights on the SQL Instance
- DBO rights on All Config, Content and Services DB.

After making sure all permission, now go to the Central Admin.

- Add new account as Managed Account
- Run the STS adm on all server to update the farm credentials `STSADM.EXE -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin "domain\username" -password "P@ssw0rd"` App server 1st...then IIS reset.
- Make sure new account is in Security Groups(ADMINISTRATORS,WSS_WPG, WSS_ADMIN_WPG).
- Configure Service Accounts

Check this for: http://tomislavspadmin.blogspot.com/2014/06/change-farm-service-account-in.html